# route giving 404 in sinatra

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I have just started working on `sinatra`, now my application is not able to navigate upto route and get data from db, I am always getting 404. This is what I am doing.

## File Structure

```
app
|---->helpers
|----->models
|----->public
|----->routes
|        |------->candidate.rb 
|        |------->init.rb
|----->app.rb
|----->config.ru
```

## config.ru

```
require './app'
run MyApp
```

## app.rb

```
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'sinatra/cross_origin'
require 'logger'
require './models/init'
require './helpers/init'
require './routes/init'


class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
configure :development do
  enable :cross_origin
  DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
  DataMapper.setup(
    :default,
    'mysql://root:@localhost/hackerrank'
  )
end
get '/' do
  File.read(File.join('public', 'index.html'))
end

DataMapper.finalize
end
```

## Command

```
bundle exec rackup -p 4567 config.ru
```

api in candidate.rb are correct but if i try to access the resource as `http://localhost:4567/#/recruiter`  I am getting 404 .
I am not able to figure out what is wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on using ERB in Sinatra?  ERB or HAML is the preferred method to render a page in a Sinatra app.

Comment: I am going through all of that, I would really appreciate if you could help me in the above problem.

Comment: Also, if you're new to Ruby, I suggest you use ActiveRecord or Sequel as your ORM instead of DataMapper.  When I picked up Ruby, i spent 3 dark months using data mapper before moving to AR, which was much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a 404, since GET '/' only works for the root page and you're trying to load /recruiter.  You can change it to GET '/:pagename' and that would fix the 404 problem instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Your codebase looks fine. When you're running your Sinatra app from the terminal, each request shows a log line such as

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2016 00:43:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0033
```

Ensure that the HTTP verb and or endpoint/route you see is the one you are expecting (perhaps you are making a POST request when accessing the resource?)